# Nesting flex box

Tags: css, performance, responsive-design, frontend, flexbox

I find flex box really useful, and since I discovered it I am tempted to use it everywhere.

#### Question

Is it a good practice to nest flex-boxes? Does having a lot of them and especially nested ones has an impact on performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short yes you will see dip in performance by around 10x we are still talking milliseconds here though.

So I would be wary of using a lot of them because one could change render speed from 10MS to 100MS a lot of them could in essence highly increase the render time.

Plus there is their comparability with browser's and their inability to play well with absolute positioning and block element's.

For now I would recommend using `display:table` and for the children `display:table-cell` & `display:table-row`.

here is an example of what I use:

```css
.align-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.t-align {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't you be using tables only for tabular data? At least that what I found quite a lot of newer, especially responsive design, articles are saying.

Comment: nope, That would be html Table's CSS Table's totally different story. check this out it's a good article http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero  I use css table for alot of my responsive work. I allways get quized on how I manage to pull of my layout's, CSS table's is that way.

Comment: Thank you!!! Very useful article, cleared a misconception I had. Only thing I have noticed there is that author suggests flex-box over table for mobile only websites. Maybe you know why in particular?

Comment: Mainly because the cross browser support is higher on mobile device's