# Good practice to use flexbox for both layout AND menus/other subcomponents?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm making a site using flexbox for the first time and want to use flex box for all of my menu sub components as well as my primary layout.  This will involve nesting a bunch of flexboxes.

Is there any issues with this?  Is this how it's usually done nowdays when using flexbox?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: On the contrary, This is a best practice question relating to quantifiable amounts of flex box usage. And was answered excellently by the other posters with some excellent advice regarding performance.
I highly suggest you let this fly.  Other people will have this exact same question because flex isn't super mainstream yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically it has been claimed that there would be a slight dip in performance. As mentioned in this same question answered last year.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757701/4427316

However, that said there is no source for claim.

W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) mentions in its flexbox specification that nesting is fine.

> Nesting of these boxes (horizontal inside vertical, or vertical inside
>   horizontal) can be used to build layouts in two dimensions.

[Read more about the flex spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)

From my experience, there is no issue with nesting flexbox element. As the spec mentions it allows you to build some "two dimension" layouts and really get the full potential of flexbox.

Comment: Yeah...This is really amazing.  I've always felt dirty using block model and it's infinite hackery.  Pretty stoked now that I can just use flex for everything.   I didn't even think about performance, however, I'm going to try it out and if it becomes an issue I can always go back.  Flexbox is so easy to use it's not alot of time lost. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no issue. Flexbox is like the block layout used by default, but establishes flex formatting contexts instead of block formatting contexts.

This allows you to use some nice features, and prevents you from using others. No layout mode is better nor privileged, you can choose the most appropriate in each situation.

That said, the block layout is usually simpler. In flexbox, flex items can grow or shrink, and thus it might be harder for a browser to do these calculations. So maybe flexbox might perform slower.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the hint about possible performance issues. Going to use flex and do some testing and see if it becomes a legit issue. If not, I'm totes pumped about flexbox. Thanks much for the help.